# Problematic Permutation Problem

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

i see a problem without any definition. would you please help me?

i want to calculate the number of permutations of 1,2,...,1392 that 696 numbers be in the natural positions (from all numbers, 696 numbers be in the correct position).

i reach two solution but  i don't know which one is correct?

a)

$$\frac{1392!}{696!}\sum_{k=0}^{696} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$$

b)

$$\binom{1392}{696}\sum_{k=0}^{696} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$$

Comment: What does "that 696 number be in the natural position" mean?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Is means that it ends up in the 696th place.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Probably means, 696 numbers are not permuted, ie. $\pi(x) = x$ for those 696 numbers

Comment: Do you mean that 696 of the numbers should be unmoved, and all the others move? Or at least 696 numbers stay put? Or the number 696 stays put?

Comment: Dear @ThomasAndrews i add detail

Comment: Given the solution he proposes, I think the question means $696$ numbers are fixed, not the number 696. @Phonon

Comment: Do you mean 696 numbers (plural) are fixed, or that the number 696 is fixed?

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom{1392}{696}$ ways to choose the fixed points, then $$696!\sum_{k=0}^{696} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$$ derangements, so (a) is the correct answer.

$$\binom{1392}{696}\cdot 696! = \frac{1392!}{696!}$$ so $(a)$ is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to help you if you show the reasoning behind your answers.  b) is almost correct-first you choose the elements which will be fixed, then you choose a derangement of the rest, which makes sure none of them stay in place, but you missed a factor of $696!$.  That will get you to a)

Comment: you means (a) is correct?

Comment: Yes, it is because ${1392 \choose 696}696!=\frac {1392!}{696!(1392-696)}!\cdot 696!=\frac {1392!}{696!}$

Answer (score 0):

You could check your answers and spot the error in one of them by looking at a simpler version with $4$ and $2$ rather than $1392$ and $696$.

So which of $\displaystyle \frac{4!}{2!}\sum_{k=0}^{2} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$ and $\displaystyle {4 \choose 2}\sum_{k=0}^{2} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$ gives a result of $6$?

Comment: Dear @Henry. i'm a mechanical engineer. :) but i think (a) is correct? am i right? i think you put answer for two case :).

Comment: @Michle Jordan: $\frac{24}{2}\left(\frac11 - \frac11+\frac12\right)$ is closer to $6$ than $6\left(\frac11 - \frac11+\frac12\right)$ is, so yes.